# Outlook VBA to update google calendar - personal use - API authorization

Tags: vba, outlook, google-api, google-oauth

I am writing an Outlook VBA for my own personal use.  I want to be able to update my google calendar when I add an event to my Outlook Calendar.  I have the following code which fires when an event has been added to my Outlook calendar:

```
Private Sub curCal_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim cAppt As AppointmentItem
Dim moveCal As AppointmentItem

' On Error Resume Next

'remove to make a copy of all items
If Item.BusyStatus = olBusy Then

    Item.Body = Item.Body & "[" & CreateGUID & "]"
    Item.Save
    
     Set cAppt = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
     
     With cAppt
         .Subject = "Copied: " & Item.Subject
         .Start = Item.Start
         .Duration = Item.Duration
         .Location = Item.Location
         .Body = Item.Body
     End With
      
     ' set the category after it's moved to force EAS to sync changes
      Set moveCal = cAppt.Move(newCalFolder)
      moveCal.Categories = "moved"
      moveCal.Save


    ' build the json string which will be sent to the google API
    
        Dim d As New Scripting.Dictionary

        d.Add "kind", "calendar#event"
        d.Add "summary", "Event Title/Summary"

        Dim d2(4) As New Scripting.Dictionary

        d2(0).Add "dateTime", Item.Start
        d.Add "start", d2(0)
        d2(1).Add "dateTime", Item.End
        d.Add "end", d2(1)
        
        Dim Json As String
        Json = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(d, Whitespace:=" ")
        
    ' send the json string via POST
    Set httpCall = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    Dim sURL As String
    sURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_personal@gmail.com/events?sendNotifications=false&fields=etag%2ChtmlLink%2Cid&pp=1&key=a_google_generated_auth_key"
    httpCall.Open "POST", sURL, False
    httpCall.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    httpCall.Send Json
    Dim sReturn As String
    sReturn = httpCall.responseText
    MsgBox (sReturn)

End If
End Sub
```

When I run the application, and I add an event to my Outlook calendar, the Json is generated correctly and is sent to google but google reports back that the calendar API requires an OAuth 2.0 key.

I am not developing this for sale, I am using this for my own personal use.

How can I use the google calendar API without going through an entire google developers registration and then setting up an OAuth 2.0 key?

I also read on the google site that if the api is called from multiple platforms, I would need to have multiple OAuth 2.0 keys.  Does this imply that if I look at my Outlook calendar on a desktop I would need an OAuth 2.0 key for that and if I look at my Outlook Calendar on my phone, I would need another OAuth 2.0 key?

If I do end up having to generate OAuth 2.0 keys, will the authorization screen pop up every time I add an event or would it just be a one time authorization?

Thank you.